# One function gives several results in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, swift, openssl

I have a method in  objective-C which I call from swift. It worked pretty well in swift 2, but in swift 3 the behaviour has changed. It gives me 3 different results, even though I send the same parameters.

Sometimes it doesnt find pfile, sometimes it fails on pin checking, sometimes works good and gives me x509.

```
char* ParsePKCS12(unsigned char* pkcs12_path, unsigned char * pin) {
printf("PARSE PATH: %s\n", pkcs12_path);
printf("PASSWORD: %s\n", pin);

NSString *pfile = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:pkcs12_path];
FILE *fp;
PKCS12 *p12;
EVP_PKEY *pkey;
X509 *cert;

BIO *databio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
STACK_OF(X509) *ca = NULL;

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pfile]) {
    NSLog(@"ok, pfile exists!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"error, pfile does not exists!");
    return "-1";
}
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();
fp = fopen([pfile UTF8String], "rb");
p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp, NULL);
fclose (fp);
if (!p12) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading PKCS#12 file\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return "-1";
}

if (!PKCS12_parse(p12, (const char *)pin, &pkey, &cert, &ca)) { //Error at parsing or pin error
    fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing PKCS#12 file\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    ERR_print_errors(databio);
    return "-1";
}

BIO *bio = NULL;
char *pem = NULL;

if (NULL == cert) {
    //return NULL;
    return "-1";
}

bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
if (NULL == bio) {
    return "-1";
}

if (0 == PEM_write_bio_X509(bio, cert)) {
    BIO_free(bio);
    //return NULL;
}

pem = (char *) malloc(bio->num_write + 1);
if (NULL == pem) {
    BIO_free(bio);
    return "-1";
}

memset(pem, 0, bio->num_write + 1);
BIO_read(bio, pem, bio->num_write);
BIO_free(bio);

PKCS12_free(p12);

return pem;
}
```

this code I call in swift like this:

```
self.x509 = String(cString:ParsePKCS12(UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: self.path),
                                           UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: "123456"))!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call

```
self.x509 = String(cString:ParsePKCS12(UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: self.path),
                                           UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: "123456"))!)
```

does not work reliably because in both

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: someSwiftString)
```

calls, the compiler creates a temporary C string representation of
the Swift string and passes that to the function. But that C string
is only valid until the `UnsafeMutablePointer` constructor returns, which means that the second
string conversion can overwrite the first, or any other undefined
behaviour.

The simplest solution would be to change  the C function to 
take constant C strings (and use the default signedness):

```
char* ParsePKCS12(const char * pkcs12_path, const char * pin)
```

Then you can simply call it as

```
self.x509 = String(cString: ParsePKCS12(self.path, "123456"))
```

and the compiler creates temporary C strings which are valid during
the call of `ParsePKCS12()`.